# magento 2 sort by discount calculation category page

Tags: category, discount, sortby

```
if($currentOrder == "discount"){
     $subject->getCollection()->order('((price_index.price - price_index.final_price) / price_index.price)', 'DESC');
}
```

how i get the discounted products at sort by option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to create a custom module to help you with custom sorting.

https://github.com/bogdanpisica/Magento2-ProductSort

Here is an example of the custom sorting mode, you can use it